# How to prevent duplicate posts via a browser refresh?

Tags: php

Will the following stop accidental duplicate entries in my database if the user posts a form and then clicks the browser refresh button?

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

        try {
            // write to database
        } catch($e) {
            // error reporting
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) - redirect always after data were successfully submitted.

Answer (score 4):

No, because if they click the refresh button (or back/forward, whatever) the browser will attempt to POST again.  What you want is the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) paradigm.  Note that this will only prevent duplicate submissions via navigation.  If you want to prevent duplicate submissions from multiple clicks of a form submission, you have to use javascript to disable the button in some way during the post attempt.

Some code:

```
<?php
   if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
      //do processing
      //303 forces a GET request
      header("Location: thank-you-page", true, 303);
      exit;
   }
   else {
      //handle bad page visit.
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any code there that does anything to differentiate between a first post and a duplicate post. What you should do is redirect the browser to a different URL after processing the POST so that if they press refresh, they're not refreshing the target of the form and POSTing again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Dan Grossman**'s method, always redirect after a POST action. Also this is another option, which adds extra security:

Add a one-time token to your forms and save it to the `$_SESSION`-variable. Then if it is used (form is submitted), remove it from the session (or create a new token). If the form is then sent again, the two tokens don't match and you have a duplicate entry (you can ignore the second for example).