# prevent duplicate data in reload page after submit form

Tags: html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent duplicate posts via a browser refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718150/how-to-prevent-duplicate-posts-via-a-browser-refresh)

I have a simple html `form` to give some info from users and register it two database.
all things are OK.
but the problem when begin that user press F5 or refresh the page; in this case previous info again register to database and create duplicate.

my question from you is how I can delete headers after register info in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution is for the server-side script that handles the POST to redirect to itself - the browser will then use a GET request to fetch the page, which can be reloaded safely. Optionally, you can copy the POSTdata to SESSIONdata and refer to it to provide feedback such as "Message sent" or "Order submitted" or "Settings saved".

Answer (score 2):

Look up [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168). That's the name of the design pattern that solves this.