# php issue form submit auto when page reload

Tags: php, html

I have a form which i want to post problem is this when ever page refresh form submit auto I just want form only form submit when I click on the button.otherwise form not post thanks in advance

```
    <?php
session_start();

//mail("ifaisal24@gmail.com","hhhhhh",print_r($_REQUEST,TRUE));
define('HOST','xxxxx');
define('USER','xxxxx');
define('PASS','Ixxxxx_');
define('DB','xxxx');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
 if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
     ?>
     <script>
     window.location = 'login2.php';
     </script>
 <?php
 }


$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);
if (isset($_POST['sender_email'])&& isset($_POST['reciver_email'])&& isset($_POST['data'])) {

    // receiving the post params

     $sender_email = $_SESSION['email'];
     $_POST['sender_email']=$_SESSION['email'];
     $reciver_email = $_POST['reciver_email'];
     $data =$sender_email.' : '. $_POST['data'];

        ///echo $sender_email;
        //die();

        // create a new chat
        $user_data = $db->storeData($data,$sender_email,$reciver_email);
        //die;
        if ($user_data) {
            // chat stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
           // $response["uid"] = $user_data["unique_id"];
            $response["user_data"]["sender_email"] = $user_data["sender_email"];
            $response["user_data"]["reciver_email"] = $user_data["reciver_email"];
            $response["user_data"]["data"] = $user_data["data"];
            $response["user_data"]["created_at"] = $user_data["created_at"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
                        }


    //    if (isset($_REQUEST['sender_email'])&& isset($_REQUEST['reciver_email'])&& isset($_REQUEST['fatch_server_data'])) {

        //                 $sender_email = $_REQUEST['sender_email'];
          //                 $reciver_email = $_REQUEST['reciver_email'];

         $sql = "select * from user_data WHERE (sender_email='$sender_email' AND reciver_email='$reciver_email') OR 
         (reciver_email ='$sender_email' AND sender_email='$reciver_email')" ;

        //$sql = "select * from user_data";
                          $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or mysql_error();
        $resultt = array(); 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                array_push($resultt,
                array(

                'data'=>$row[3],
                'created_at'=>$row[4]
                //   'email'=>$row[3]
                ));
            }  
            //            }         
 json_encode(array("resultt"=>$resultt));

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<?php
define('HOST','mxxxxx');
define('USER','axxxxxxx');
define('PASS','Ixxxxxxx_');
define('DB','axxxxxxxx');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from users";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
    array(
     //  'id'=>$row[0],
      'email'=>$row[3], 
));
} 
 json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#userschat { 
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    color:black;
    border: 5px teal solid;
    height: 325px;
    width: 300px;

 overflow-y:scroll;
}
#usersOnLine { 

    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    color:black;
    border: 10px teal solid;
    height: 625px;
    width: 300px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
#allcon{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    color:black;
    border: 10px teal solid;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
}
#contact{
    float:right;
}
#all{
    float:left;
}
#data {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 5px teal solid;
    float:left;
    margin-top:1px;
}

#send {
    border: 5px teal solid;
    width: 57px;
    height: 30px;
    float:right;
    margin:1px;
}
.container{
    width:970px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#messageForm{

}
.clickAble{
                    display: inline-block;;
                    cursor:pointer; 
                }

</style>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
</head>
<body bgcolor="beige">>
<div class="container">

<form method="post" action="login2.php">
<input type="submit" id="l_btn" name="l_btn" value="Logout" />

</form>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
   // here is where your code would be included
    session_destroy();
   header("Location:chat.php" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}


?>


<div id = "welcome"><h2>Welcome to Chat</h2>
<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>
</div>

<div id = "all"> 
<h1> Chat Box</h1>
<div id="receiver">
                <h3>receiver</h3>
                <!-- NOTICE THAT THIS IS NEW NOW... -->
                <!-- IT'S IMPORTANT THAT YOU HAVE THIS PARAGRAPH EXACTLY AS IT IS HERE -->
                <p class='bubbled-data'></p>
            </div>
<div id="sender"><h3>sender</h3>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>
    </div>
<div id="userschat">
<h4 style = " margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 7px">
<?php
foreach($resultt as $key => $val)
{
    echo $val['data'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $val['created_at'];   
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
 ?>
 </h4>
</div>
<form id="messageForm" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="sender_email" id="sender_email" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="reciver_email" id="reciver_email" value="">
<input type="text" name="data" id="data"   placeholder="data" onFocus="fun1(this)" onBlur="fun2(this)" required=""   />

    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</div> 

<div id = "contact">
<div id = "allcon"> 
  <h1 style = "  text-align: center; margin-top: 4px;">   All Contacts   </h1>
</div>
<div id="usersOnLine" >
<h2 style = " margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 7px">
<?php
          foreach($result as $key => $val){
          echo "<span class='clickAble'>" . $val['email'] . "</span>";
          echo "<br>";
          echo "<br>";
         }
 ?>
 </h2>
</div>
</div>

</div>





        <!-- JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

       var objDiv = document.getElementById("userschat");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            var receiver = $("#receiver");
            var clickAbles = $(".clickAble");

            receiver.find(".bubbled-data").text(localStorage.getItem("nameValue"));
           $("#reciver_email").val(localStorage.getItem("nameValue"));
            // BIND THE clickAble SPAN TO AN ON-CLICK EVENT...
            // SO THAT WITH EACH CLICK, YOU CAN SIMPLE APPEND THE CONTENT OF THAT SPAN TO THE RECEIVER DIV
            clickAbles.on("click", function (evt) {
                var nameValue = $(this).text();
                receiver.find(".bubbled-data").text(nameValue);

                $("#reciver_email").val(nameValue);
                localStorage.setItem("nameValue", nameValue);


            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the full code.i edit it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent duplicate posts via a browser refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718150/how-to-prevent-duplicate-posts-via-a-browser-refresh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Post-Redirect-Get code example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142809/simple-post-redirect-get-code-example)

Comment: just check echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die(); what are the values

Comment: Tell me I will check for solution

Comment: after success you just redirect the page header('Location:index.php'); exit();

Comment: @ jothi, He is just checking condition here

Comment: its all browser functionality you have to restrict using client side javascript

Comment: header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();  redirect unset the last post value or get value or any request

Comment: let me know if my answer helped you

Comment: if your form resubmission  mean what kind of  problem your had ?

Comment: @jothi  its again submit form when page refresh

Comment: thats why im telling that after success you just redirect the page header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); exit();

Answer (score 0):

A [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) design would be a viable solution to your problem. An example of code that would accomplish this is:

```
if ($_POST) {
   // here is where your code would be included

   header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
```

The `header` function then redirects the user to the same page, which means that the `$_POST` information is lost, hence refreshing the page would not re-send the form.

Comment: will you please edit my full code how to use it i am new in php

Comment: I'm guiding you on how you can fix the problem. If you give me 2 pages of code to fix, I would then not be doing this site justice since it is a Q and A forum. But to help guide you again in the right direction, place something like `echo "test<br>";`  under the `// here is where your code would be included` comment in my above code. You'll see that if you load the page the first time (when submitting the form), you'll see "test" on the page, however when refreshing, it will no longer be there.

Comment: @Malik oh and if this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept it (green checkmark) so that future readers/users know it worked for you.

Comment: when i refresh page without click on button form auto submit

Comment: @Malik edit your question and include the php that manages the form so that I can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Webeng, This is not the solution what Malik is asking

Comment: @Malik , I have checked your code and this is working fine

Comment: i have two problem one is form auto submit when page reload and other button not destroy session here

Comment: @Malik/Webeng please upvote my answer for balance. You please check that any header() or js is not doing so.

Comment: when i click on logout button its not destry the seesion

Comment: @webeng can we apply this to any one form only?